# cmd alias for printing out sizeof folder cygwin

Tags: windows, cmd, cygwin, alias, doskey

I currently try to figure out How exactly i can generate a Doskey Alias that allows Pipes.

I want to gather the foldersize in kB.

I have tried

> `alias dirsize=du -P -c -a -b $1 | grep total | awk '{print "Folder has: " $1 "kB"}'`

But i simply get the Output

> `Folder has: kB`

When I just use

```
dirsize=du -P -c -a -b $1 | grep total
```

It gets me

```
C:\>dirsize Temp
1364201 total
```

But how do I use the awk pipe now?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to quote your alias: `alias dirsize="quoted content"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
doskey dirsize=du -P -c -a -b $1 $b grep -E "total$" $b awk "{i=1;print \"Has \" $i \" bytes\"}"
```

Inside a doskey alias

- the pipe character is `$b`
- all instances of `$1` will be replaced with the first argument in the call to the alias, so, the `$1` inside the `awk` command will be replaced during the alias parse and at execution time it will not be a reference to the argument

The usual solution to this problem inside a `doskey` alias is to convert the `$1` into something that will not interfere the command execution but avoids doskey parser to handle it. To do it, the usual solution is to use `$^1`, but in this case, this sequence is not handled by `cmd`, it is handled by `awk` and the `^` is not considered a escape character.

We need to solve it inside `awk`, replacing the direct `$1` using a variable (`i`) to store the index to retrieve and replacing the `$1` with `$i` that has no special meaning inside `doskey` aliases.